# Fourier representation for $\tan(x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Q: Which Fourier representation is suitable for $f(x) = \tan(x)$: Fourier trigonometric series, Fourier half-range expansion, or Fourier integral and why?

Well I searched and found that:
$\tan(x)$ cannot be expanded as a Fourier series since $\tan(x)$ not satisfies Dirichlet’s.

Isn't there any Fourier representation for $\tan(x)$?

Thanks ^_^

Comment: @Tharsis thanks for the edit ^^

Answer (score 8):

In terms of generalized functions, there is a Fourier series for $\tan(x)$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.  To see this, we proceed as follows.

Let $f(x)=\tan(x)$ and let $F(x)\equiv \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ for $0 \le x< \pi/2$ be an antiderivative of $f(x)$ on $[0,\pi/2)$.  Clearly, we have $F(x)=-\log(\cos(x))$.

Next, note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\log(\cos(x))&=\log(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})-\log(2)\\\\
&=\log(1+e^{i2x})-\log(2)-ix\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}e^{i2nx}}{n}-\log(2)-ix
\tag1
\end{align}$$

which after taking the real part of $(1)$ reveals

$$\int_0^x \tan(t)\,dt= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \cos(2nx)}{n}\tag2$$

If we formally differentiate both sides of $(2)$ with respect to $x$, we arrive at the relationship

$$\tan(x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\sin(2nx)\tag3$$

which is obviously incorrect in the context of real analysis since the series on the right-hand side of $(3)$ diverges for $x\in (0,\pi/2)$.

We can assign, however, a meaning to $(3)$ in the context of generalized functions.  Recall that for any suitable test function $\phi$ that has compact support on $[0,\pi/2]$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2} F(x)\phi'(x)\,dx&=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan(x)\phi(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^{\pi/2} \sum_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\cos(2nx)\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(2nx)\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(2nx)\phi(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$

Then, in distribution we can write

$$\tan(x)\sim 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\sin(2nx)\tag4$$

where we interpret $(4)$ for to mean that for any suitable test function with compact support on $[0,\pi/2]$, we have

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan(x)\phi(x)\,dx=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(2nx)\phi(x)\,dx\tag 5$$

for $x\in[0,\pi/2)$

Finally, exploiting the symmetry and periodicity we see that $(5)$ holds for all periodic test functions that vanish at odd integral multiples of $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\tan(x)$ is odd with period $\pi$, so the half-range fourier coefficients would be given by
$\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan(x)\sin(\frac{nx}{2}) \mathrm{d}x$. But the integral diverges. However, if $f(x)=\tan(x)$ for $a<x<b$, where $a>-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $b<\frac{\pi}{2}$, the periodic etension of $f(x)$ has a fourier transform.

Comment: Thanks @Angela ,, but how would I calculate half range expansion while it goes to infinity at x = π/2 Can't Get it :S , and what is the diff. here between F.Series and F half range expansion ?

Comment: @angelarichardson The Fourier series does exist as a distribution as I showed in the post on this page.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I'll rescale trivially so that $\tan(\pi x)$ is $1$-periodic. You are looking for the Fourier series expansion of:
$$
\tan(\pi x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} C_ne^{i2\pi n x} \\
C_n = \int_0^1\tan(\pi x)e^{-i2\pi nx}dx
$$

Technically, you have a problem because the integral does not converge. Appealing to more general definitions of Fourier series will not help either. $\tan(\pi x)$ is not in $L^2(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$ and more generally is not a distribution because of its poles (btw, no need to check if it is tempered since it is periodic). You'll need to be more precise in handling them. There are many alternatives, giving different solutions to your original problem.

Since you are asking for a Fourier series, you are assuming 1-periodicity, so all poles need to be treated the same. I the following I will take this path and show you three standard choices. In general, you could treat the poles differently breaking the 1-periodicity so that your original problem does not even have a solution.

The standard choice is to take the Cauchy principal value for all poles (could be useful for parity considerations). Another is to slightly shift the poles in the imaginary direction (could be useful for causality considerations). Note that this shifting of poles is equivalent to changing the integration contour. In general, this is because the inverse of $x$ is ambiguous for distributions, it is determined up to an additive term proportional to $\delta$, which is equivalent to shifting/avoiding the pole in complex integration. This arbitrary delta contribution at the pole means that rigorously, the coefficients of the Fourier series are defined up to a common additive constant.

For actual computations, it is often easier to expand in Laurent series than Fourier series. Writing $z=e^{i2\pi x}$,
$$
\tan(\pi x) = f(z) \\
f(z) = i\frac{1-z}{1+z} \\
C_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz
$$
Once again, there is a pole at $z=-1$, so the contour integration is meaningless.

The first natural approach is to shift the contour and avoid the pole at $z=-1$ by going inside the unite circle (alternatively, shrink the circle to $|z|=1-\epsilon$). Back to the $x$ integration, this is equivalent to avoiding the pole by swerving slightly in the negative imaginary direction (alternatively, lower the segment to $[0,1]-i\epsilon$). A third equivalent way is to define the original function to be the weak limit of:
$$
\tan(\pi(x+i\epsilon))
$$
with $\epsilon\to 0^+$. This is now a legitimate distribution for which the Fourier series makes sense. Since the contour now does not enclose any poles, the coefficients are the ones of the Taylor series of $f$ (i.e. automatically the coefficients $C_n=0$ for $n<0$, which is the analogue of causal solutions in physics):
$$
\frac{1}{1+z} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^nz^n \\
f(z) = i+2i\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^nz^n
$$
so:
$$
C_n = \begin{cases}
0 & n<0\\
i & n=0\\
2i(-1)^n & n>0
\end{cases}
$$
i.e.
$$
\tan(\pi(x+i\epsilon)) = i+2i\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^ne^{i2\pi n x}
$$
Conversely, the contour could have been chosen to avoid the pole by going outside the unit circle. This would define the original function to be the weak limit of:
$$
\tan(\pi(x-i\epsilon))
$$
with $\epsilon\to0^-$. This time, the contour encloses a pole, so the Laurent series is relevant (i.e. automatically the coefficients $C_n=0$ for $n<0$, which is the analogue of anti-causal solutions in physics):
$$
\frac{1}{z+1} = -\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}(-1)^nz^n \\
f(z) = -i-2i\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}(-1)^nz^{n}
$$
so:
$$
C_n = \begin{cases}
0 & n>0\\
-i & n=0\\
-2i(-1)^n & n<0
\end{cases}
$$
i.e.
$$
\tan(\pi(x-i\epsilon)) = -i-2i\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}(-1)^ne^{i2\pi n x}
$$
According to the [Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem), taking the half sum, you recover the convention of where the original function is defined by the Cauchy principal value (which is the convention implicitly chosen by Mark Viola):
$$
C_n = \begin{cases}
0 & n=0\\
i\text{sgn}(n)(-1)^n & n\neq0
\end{cases} \\
$$
which gives:
\begin{align}
PV[\tan(\pi x)] &= i\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z^*}\text{sgn}(n)(-1)^ne^{i2\pi n x}\\
&= -2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\sin(2\pi n x)\\
\end{align}

As anticipated at the very beginning, the three conventions lead to the same Fourier coefficients up to a common additive constant. The convergence of the sums is to be interpreted in the weak sense, meaning that you first need to take the bracket with a suitable test function and then take the limit.

Hope this helps.