# Transform the function $f(x) =\tan^2 x$ into Fourier series for $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I am stuck with this problem. Firstly the boundaries make me worry, because I get that the integral is infinity, and while calculating $a_n$ i have to solve the integral $\int \tan^2x cos 4nx dx$ which seems impossible. Any tips on how to solve this problem?

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399383/fourier-representation-for-tanx) is related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The framework of Fourier-series with trigonometric basis functions only works in $L^2$, ie. the space of square integrable functions. This means that you can write a function as a Fourier-series iff its square is integrable.

However, $\tan(x)^2\notin L^2$. Take $x$ near $\frac \pi 2$: There, to the first order, $\sin x \approx 1$, and $\cos x\approx -x+\pi/2$. Therefore, locally $\tan(x)^2=\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)^2\approx \frac 1{(-x+\pi/2)^2}$. The singularity on the r.h.s. is obviously not square integrable, and so $\tan(x)^2$ isn't either.

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar method to my [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399383/fourier-representation-for-tanx), you can make sense of the the question by slightly tweaking the original problem. As DominikS explains, $\tan^2$ is not locally integrable, so it is not even a proper distribution. You'll need to modify it slightly to make it a legitimate one.

The natural analogue would be to generalise the Cauchy principal value. For this, you can use [Hadamard regularisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization). It has nice properties like conserving parity. Note that it defines a distribution, so the Fourier series will not converge in the usual sense, but rather converge weakly.

I'll rescale for convenience the function to be $\tan^2(\pi x)$ which is $1$ periodic. I can capitalise the previous calculations by noticing that:
$$
\tan^2(\pi x) = -1+\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{d}{dx}\tan(\pi x)
$$
so by taking the derivative of the previous expression:
$$
\tan(\pi x) = -2\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z^*}(-1)^n\sin(2\pi n x)\\
$$
I get:
$$
\tan^2(\pi x) = -1-4\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z^*}(-1)^nn\cos(2\pi n x)
$$

Note that you could alternatively choose to define it using the analogues of causal/anti-causal solutions. The calculation can be made analogously by considering Laurent series.

Hope this helps.